# Selecting child parent hierarchy in a single row pl sql

Tags: oracle, plsql

Oracle 11g - Select query help.

The table "data_table" has three fields as below and keep a child parent relation as follows -

```
user_code   -> description  -> parent_code

A          -> Root ID   ->    B

B        ->   Level1    ->    C

C      ->     Level2    ->    D

D    ->       Level3    ->    E

E       ->    Level4    ->     F
```

The requirement is to post this hierarchy in a single line as below.

```
**
Root ID -> Level1 ->    Level2  -> Level3->     Level4

A   -> B    -> C    -> D    -> E **
```

What are my options? please help..

Now I use below query, but doesn't looks good.

```
 SELECT e.user_code   user_code,
    d.description user_description,
    e.parent_code level1,
    a.parent_code level2 ,
    b.parent_code level3 ,
    c.parent_code level4
FROM    data_table e,
    data_table a,
    data_table b,
    data_table c,
    data_table d
WHERE   e.user_code = d.user_code
AND     b.user_code = a.parent_code
AND     c.user_code = b.parent_code
AND     e.parent_code = a.user_code
```

Comment: are you wanting the display to output the results in separate columns, or are you ok with the results being returned in a single column? Also, is there a fixed limit to how many levels there could be?

Comment: I would like to have the data in separate columns.

Comment: And is there a fixed limit to the number of levels there could be?

Comment: Yes 5 levels.  Can you please rephrase your query?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a hierarchichal query connecting parent and child through user_code and parent_code. Something like this:

```
WITH data_table AS (
   SELECT 'A' user_code, 'Root ID' description, 'B' parent_code FROM dual
   UNION
   SELECT 'B' user_code, 'Level1' description, 'C' parent_code FROM dual
   UNION
   SELECT 'C' user_code, 'Level2' description, 'D' parent_code FROM dual
   UNION
   SELECT 'D' user_code, 'Level3' description, 'E' parent_code FROM dual
   UNION
   SELECT 'E' user_code, 'Level4' description, 'F' parent_code FROM dual
) 
SELECT MAX(SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(user_code,'->'))
FROM data_table
CONNECT BY prior parent_code = user_code 
START WITH user_code = 'A'
```

SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH shows the path but if you want the whole path in a single line you need to get the MAX.

You can read more on hierarchichal queries [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries003.htm)

Comment: Thanks @pablomatico, I would like to have data posted in the separate column, not a concatenated string. say a table viz field1 with Root ie A, field2 with B, field3 with C etc

Comment: Why would you want that? You could easily change the query to get each level in a different row but if you want them in different columns you would need to know in advance how many levels there are

Comment: Thanks @pablomatico, I have only 5 levels, for sure and the description not represent any level.

Answer (score 0):

If there's a fixed number of levels that you know about, you can do the following:

```
with sample_data as (select 'A' user_code, 'Root ID' description, 'B' parent_code from dual union all
                     select 'B' user_code, 'Level 1' description, 'C' parent_code from dual union all
                     select 'C' user_code, 'Level 2' description, 'D' parent_code from dual union all
                     select 'D' user_code, 'Level 3' description, 'E' parent_code from dual union all
                     select 'E' user_code, 'Level 4' description, 'F' parent_code from dual union all
                     select 'G' user_code, 'Root ID' description, 'H' parent_code from dual union all
                     select 'H' user_code, 'Level 1' description, 'I' parent_code from dual union all
                     select 'I' user_code, 'Level 2' description, 'J' parent_code from dual union all
                     select 'J' user_code, 'Level 3' description, 'K' parent_code from dual),
             res as (select sd.user_code,
                            sd.description,
                            connect_by_root(sd.user_code) top_node
                     from   sample_data sd
                     connect by sd.user_code = prior sd.parent_code
                     start with sd.description = 'Root ID')
select root_id,
       level1,
       level2,
       level3,
       level4
from   res
pivot  (max(user_code) for description in ('Root ID' as root_id,
                                           'Level 1' as level1,
                                           'Level 2' as level2,
                                           'Level 3' as level3,
                                           'Level 4' as level4))
order by top_node;

ROOT_ID LEVEL1 LEVEL2 LEVEL3 LEVEL4
------- ------ ------ ------ ------
A       B      C      D      E     
G       H      I      J
```

If there's an unknown number of levels, then you're going to have to investigate dynamic pivoting - there are plenty of examples of how to do dynamic pivoting if you search Google.

Comment: Thanks @Boniest , I know that, I have only 5 levels clearly, then can I bring down query to less lines? and the description field not represent any levels, its just description of user code.